# Como eu faço um insert into usando SQL dinâmico e execute sp_executesql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

Eu estou tentando fazer um insert usando cursor e o execute sp_executesql usando variável, na primeira vez ele executou e não retornou nada, fui na tabela e não havia adicionado nenhum registro.
Então eu executei a segunda vez e apareceu a mensagem de chave duplicada, mas não foi adicionado registro na tabela.

Alguém tem ideia do que pode estar acontecendo e onde estou falhando? Abaixo segue o código que estou tentando fazer.

'''

```
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    Begin
        DECLARE @COLUNA VARCHAR(100), @COLUNAS VARCHAR(MAX), @CLONAR NVARCHAR(MAX), @NovoId int, @PedidoId varchar(11), @vInsertInto NVARCHAR(MAX);

        --- Inicializar a variavel
        SET @COLUNAS    = ''
        SET @NovoId     = ''
        SET @CLONAR     = ''
        SET @PedidoId   = '1234'

        --sempre declare que o cursor é do tipo LOCAL FAST_FORWARD.
        --Local diz que é o scopo da execuçao e FAST_FORWARD significa que ele so vai pra frente.
        DECLARE CURCOLUNAS CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR SELECT COLUMN_NAME
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE   TABLE_CATALOG   = 'banco'
                AND TABLE_SCHEMA= 'dbo'
                AND TABLE_NAME  = 'tabela'
        ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
        OPEN CURCOLUNAS
            FETCH NEXT FROM CURCOLUNAS INTO @COLUNA
            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
            BEGIN
                SET @COLUNAS = @COLUNAS + ',' + @COLUNA
                FETCH NEXT FROM CURCOLUNAS INTO @COLUNA --- O into nesta linha
            END

            SET @COLUNAS= Right(@COLUNAS, len(@COLUNAS)-1)
            --SET @CLONAR = N'SELECT '+@COLUNAS+' FROM tabela WHERE Id = '+@PedidoId;
            SET @vInsertInto = N'INSERT INTO tabela ('+@COLUNAS+') SELECT '+@COLUNAS+' FROM tabela WHERE Id = '+@PedidoId;

            SET IDENTITY_INSERT [banco].[dbo].[tabela] ON
            --EXECUTE sp_executesql @CLONAR;
            EXECUTE sp_executesql @vInsertInto;
            SET IDENTITY_INSERT [banco].[dbo].[tabela] OFF

        --SET @NovoId=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
        --RETURN  @NovoId
        CLOSE CURCOLUNAS;
        DEALLOCATE CURCOLUNAS;
    End
```

'''

Comment: Cara, se na segunda vez deu chave duplicada, o primeiro insert deve ter funcionado... O que pode estar acontecendo, é que esse insert está transacionado, você está abrindo transação ou essa procedure é chamada dentro de uma?

Comment: Funciona direito isso, mudei para uma tabela numa db de testes, e inseriu os registos sem problema.

Comment: @DanielMendes A procedure é chamada num sistema, não está dentro de outra procedure ou algo do tipo. Eu preciso gravar um registro e devolver o id do novo registro mas no meu banco não aparece o novo registro. Eu faço SELECT MAX(ID) da tabela e continua no mesmo id, como não tenho grande conhecimento eu não sei onde posso estar errando.

Comment: @ErnestoCasanova Eu fico feliz que está correto e você conseguiu fazer rodar. Mas comigo está ficando no mesmo lugar, eu não tenho grande experiência então não sei onde posso estar errando. Depois de rodar eu faço SELECT MAX(ID) da tabela e não muda o id. Eu tenho que gravar um novo registro e depois pegar o novo ID e devolver para o sistema que chamou a procedure. Isso pode ser cache? Uma dúvida agora, como deu duplicação de chava se sempre vai ser adicionado um novo registro?

Comment: Quando eu rodo aparecem as mensagems abaixo:

Mensagem 2627, Nível 14, Estado 1, Linha 1
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Tabela'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Tabela'.
The statement has been terminated.
Mensagem 16917, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 43
Cursor is not open.

Comment: Pessoal eu consegui fazer funcionar na minha máquina, mas eu tive que fazer alguns ajustes:
- Depois do SET NOCOUNT ON; eu adicionei o SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT ON;
- Eu retirei as duas linhas (SET IDENTITY_INSERT [banco].[dbo].[tabela] ON)
- Coloquei no lugar o seguinte (BEGIN TRANSACTION;EXECUTE sp_executesql @vInsertInto;COMMIT TRANSACTION;)

Agora preciso pegar o id gerado e devolver.